# Use two file upload Button in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use two file upload buttons in codeigniter like below

```
<label class="control-label" for="default">PO File</label>
<input type="file"  id="po_file" name="po_file"  multiple="multiple" >
<label class="control-label" for="default">Invoice File</label>
<input type="file"  id="in_file" name="in_file"  multiple="multiple" >
```

in controller

```
    $file1 = $_FILES['po_file']['name'];
    $file2 = $_FILES['in_file']['name'];
    $config['upload_path'] = $pathToUpload;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['overwrite' ] =TRUE;
    $config['max_size'] =0;


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        echo $this->upload->display_errors();

        // $this->load->view('file_view', $error);
    }
    else
    {

        $this->upload->do_upload(file1);
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_name = $upload_data['file_name'];
    }
```

I tried like this but it gave 
You did not select a file to upload.
Any help how to do this???
thank you

Answer (score 3):

Seeing your form in the question, I'm assuming that you want two files to be uploaded from two different input fields. Is that it ?

So, doing it in your way, your form should be as :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">    <!-- enctype="multipart/form-data" is must, method 'post' or 'get' is depend on your requirement -->

    <?php
        if( !empty( $notification ) )
        {
            echo '
            <p>Notifications : </p>
            <p>'.$notification.'</p>';    <!-- For the status of the uploaded files ( error or success ) -->
        }
    ?>

    <label for="default">PO File</label>
    <input type="file" name="po_file">    <!-- no need to add "multiple" attribute, unless you want multiple files to be uploaded in the same input field-->
    <label for="default">Invoice File</label>
    <input type="file" name="in_file">

    <input type="submit" name="upload">

</form>
```

And your controller should be as :

```
class Image extends CI_Controller {

    private $data;    // variable to be used to pass status of the uploaded files ( error or success )

    function __construct()
    {
        // some code
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        $this->data['notification'] = '';

        if( $this->input->post('upload') )    // if form is posted
        {
            // setting the config array

            $config['upload_path']      = 'uploads/';    // $pathToUpload ( in your case )
            $config['allowed_types']    = 'pdf';
            $config['max_size']         = 0;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);    // loading the upload class with the config array

            // uploading the files

            $this->lets_upload( 'po_file' );    // this function passes the input field name from the form as an argument

            $this->lets_upload( 'in_file' );    // same as above, function is defined below
        }

        $this->load->view('form', $this->data);    // loading the form view along with the member variable 'data' as argument
    }

    public function lets_upload( $field_name )    // this function does the uploads
    {
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload( $field_name ))    // ** do_upload() is a member function of upload class, and it is responsible for the uploading files with the given configuration in the config array
        {
            $this->data['notification'] .= $this->upload->display_errors();    // now if there's is some error in uploading files, then errors are stored in the member variable 'data'
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();    // if succesful, then infomation about the uploaded file is stored in the $upload_data variable

            $this->data['notification'] .= $upload_data['file_name']." is successfully uploaded.<br>";    // name of uploaded file is stored in the member variable 'data'
        }
    }
}
```

Now suppose, you want a new image file to be uploaded in a different location or whatever, from the same form; then in the config array, you only have to change the array elements which you want to be different as :

```
$config['upload_path'] = '/gallery';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
```

Then you have to initialize the config array as :

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);    // *** this is important ***
```

and then you have to load the upload class with this new config as :

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

and now you can call the lets_upload() function :

```
$this->lets_upload( 'img_file' );
```

in the upload() function.

Answer (score 0):

first in your php.ini 
   file_uploads = On

Second be sure of that

```
<form action="controller/action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

third check that on codeigniter documentaion about upload file .
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

don't forget the extension of files allowd

Comment: i was able to upload file when i used userfile as a name of the textbox
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /> but i want to rename it to my own name

Answer (score 0):

If you see upload.php library file under system folder then you'll know that CI takes 'userfile' field name as default, So when you do

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    echo $this->upload->display_errors();

    // $this->load->view('file_view', $error);
}

//Passing parameter empty, then CI search for 'userfile'.
```

Try passing field name as you have done in else condition, or setting one of the input field name to 'userfile'.